C# и Яндекс таблицы - автоматизация чтения и записи данных в ячейки
Имеется проект на базе Гугл таблиц: записываем данные в локальную БД - информация появляется в таблице, записываем данные в Гугл таблицу - меняется информация в локальной БД. Перенос данных выполняется с помощью проекта на C#.
На днях появилась необходимость перенести данный проект с иностранного ресурса на отечественный. Из опций в голову приходят только Яндекс таблицы.
Вопрос 1: есть ли возможность (и если есть, то как) сделать аналогичный проект на базе Яндекс таблиц? В интернете нужной информации, увы, не нашёл.
Вопрос 2: какие отечественные платформы подойдут в качестве альтернативы? Критерии:
- возможность доступа к интерфейсу таблиц из браузера;
- функционал и интерфейс по аналогии с таблицами Гугла;
- возможность управления таблицами извне с помощью C# (в приоритете) или Python
Всем спасибо

Я работал с Яндексом и не могу рекомендовать его, так как у них нет софта, который позволяет изменять данные "на лету". У Гугла есть довольно удобные инструменты: все понятно, можно работать через API, удалять, создавать, загружать и редактировать таблицы. Если вы любите сложности, возможно, сможете попробовать Яндекс, но лучше заранее подготовьтесь к возможным трудностям.
